# A nonlinear differntial equation $f'''-(f')^2+1=0,$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find a way to solve the equation below

> $$f'''-(f')^2+1=0,$$

with boundary conditions:

$$
f'(0)=0,\\ \,f'(\infty)=1\\f''(\infty)=0.
$$

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: HINT: Multiply by $f''(x)$.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a "nice" solution to this. A solution exists in terms of the Weierstrass zeta function according to Wolfram Alpha, but that doesn't seem so nice.

Comment: @CameronWilliams. I bet that "not nice" is a real understatement.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Actually the initial conditions make that there is a nice solution, namely, something similar to $$f'(x)=3\left(\frac{5e^{\sqrt{2}x}-1}{5e^{\sqrt{2}x}+1}\right)^2-2,$$ from which $f(x)$ can be deduced by integration (with an explicit primitive).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici See above.

Comment: And, unrelatedly, this should be closed for lack of personal input.

Comment: @Did. This is a good surprise ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: *Sorry, the two $5$ in the formula for $f'(x)$ above should read $(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)^2$. I think. Or something similar... :-)

Comment: Thanks ! I was "playing" with the formula and faced some trouble !

Answer (score 6):

First of all it becomes 2nd order when you set $g=f'$ and obtain
$$
g''-g^2+1=0.
$$
Then multiplying by $g'$ we get
$$
g'g''-g^2g'+g'=0.
$$
Integrating we have
$$
\frac{1}{2}(g')^2-\frac{1}{3}g^3+g=c,
$$
for some $c$ constant. Then solving w.r.t. $g'$:
$$
g'=\pm\sqrt{c'-2g+\frac{2}{3}g^3}.
$$
It does look like it can get any better after that unless you you initial conditions...

Comment: @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis: But how to substitute the conditions?

Comment: @doraemonpaul: From the inital data.

Comment: @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis: You will get the general solution $f(\text{independent variable})=C_3-6^\frac{2}{3}~\zeta\left(\dfrac{\text{independent variable}+C_1}{\sqrt[3]6};2\sqrt[3]6,C_2\right)$ , but do you really have confident to handle all conditions?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Indeed the initial conditions allow to complete this, see my comment to main.